# How to display s3 image in browser

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mime-types, content-type

How to display s3 image in the browser, now it is getting downloading every time when I try to open it in a browser. I have set the content type but still, I am facing the same issue.
here is my code

```
var params = {
 Key: 'upload/' + req.file.originalname,
Body: data,
ContentType:'image/jpeg',
ACL: 'public-read'
};
s3bucket.upload(params, function(err, aws_images) {
console.log(aws_images)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are wanting to have images served from Amazon S3 cached in browsers.

To do this, you can set `cache-control` metadata on the objects.

See:

- [Amazon S3 images cache-control not being applied](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43860173/174777)
- [How to add cache control in AWS S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22501465/174777)